# Disable auto zoom on input fields in webview on IOS6

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

Does anyone know if there is a possibility to remove the auto zoom on input fields in a webview on IOS6 ?

We have made a mobile site that is shown in a webview, and on IOS5- it works perfektly but when we try and open it on an iPad with a fixed width/height then the hole content is moved when entering a input field.

For IOS5- the meta tag viewport with user-scalable set to no works perfectly but on IOS6 i breaks.

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: did you find the solution on this?

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width,user-scalable=0">
```

it works for me.